# Node Mongo REST Service Post

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, rest

I have created a REST service using Node.js and MongoDB for using in one of my Android app.
The get methods is working as expected when called from Android App.
I am trying to build a JSON object from Android App with necessary details and post to the service.I am unable to post to my collections. Below is the code snippet I have used in my Node.js

```
app.post('/accounts/put/:uObject', function(req, res, next) {
  var username=uObject.name;

  db.collection('test').insert({"username":username},function(err,docs){if(err){
                res.send("There was some problem during insertions of linkes");
            }
           else{
                res.send("Fail");

           } });

});
```

What Am I doing wrong in this? I am getting the object as parameter and getting the values inside the function and passing to the insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the parameter from the route you need to use `req.params`, in your case `req.params.uObject`. Also common practice in JavaScript is to return early upon a condition being met.

```
app.post('/accounts/put/:uObject', function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.params.uObject;

    db.collection('test').insert({
        "username": username
    }, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send("There was some problem during insertions of linkes");
        }
        res.send("Fail");
    });

});
```

Comment: So does the JSON objects inserts as a whole into the collection? I need not extract each and every values separately?