# Calling Node REST service from Android

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, rest, curl

I have written a REST post method as described in the answer of my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26462107/node-mongo-rest-service-post/26462278#26462278).

When try with the curl command post service works as expected

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":Tom,"mail":"xyz@123.com"}' http://localhost:3080/accounts/put/
```

Now I have hosted the node application in a VPS such that it can be accessed via internet. Other get services are accessible and data is populated correctly.

If I try to execute the same curl command it's throwing error as below

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":Tom,"mail":"xyz@123.com"}' http://MyServerIP:3080/accounts/put/
```

The error is

```
 Cannot call method &#39;insert&#39; of undefined
        at Object.app.get.db.collection.find.accounts [as handle] (/home/balaaagi/nodeapps/meanservice/server.js:62:18)
at next_layer (/home/balaaagi/nodeapps/meanservice/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/balaaagi/nodeapps/meanservice/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at c (/home/balaaagi/nodeapps/meanservice/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24)
    at param (/home/balaaagi/nodeapps/meanservice/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:268:14)
    at param (/home/balaaagi/nodeapps/meanservice/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:16)
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/balaaagi/nodeapps/meanservice/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:296:3)
    at next (/home/balaaagi/nodeapps/meanservice/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
    at next (/home/balaaagi/nodeapps/meanservice/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
    at next (/home/balaaagi/nodeapps/meanservice/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
```

When I try to the call the POST from Android application also I face similar error as output for `EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity())`
Is my JSON object not getting passed/something wrong with my hosting of the service in VPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The localhost curl commands were successful because each time when I modified the server.js I restarted the node.
In my VPS I have used forever to run the node continuosly. When deployed the latest server.js into my VPS I missed to restart node. Hence this issue was caused because it was referring old code.

Also I killed all node using `killall node` in VPS which kills all task named node in the server.
Then restarted my Node with forever. REST Post worked both from curl as well as from my Android App. Cross checked with DB on the successful insertion of data into the DB.